# Чтобы input() не останавливал программу

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Возможно ли выполнять программу, пока пользователь вводит текст для input()?

Comment: выполняется в отдельном потоке как вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользуйся:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from threading import Thread

class InputThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            s = input('Введите строку: ')
            print(s)


class PrintThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('Me work!')
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    it = InputThread().start()
    pt = PrintThread().start()
```